# Why does changing an 'add' to a logical or devour 7 CPLD macrocells?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, programmable-logic

I have a design that's synthesizing to about 50 macrocells.

I have this section of code:

```
module levers2(
     input [2:0] LL,
     input [2:0] RL,
    output reg [10:0] DIVISOR,
    output reg FAULT
    );

reg [10:0] grid[0:63];
wire [5:0] tmp = (LL<<3)+RL;
(snip)
```

`tmp` is for all intents, an address line.  I have two 3-bit input lines and I'm combining them to make a 6-bit address line.  So I shift `LL` by three bits and add `RL`.  When I synthesize, I get a 47 macrocell result.

However, if I change the operator to a logical or:

```
wire [5:0] tmp = (LL<<3) | RL;
```

The design synthesizes to 54 macrocells.  That's 7 macrocells lost for what?!

I would think a bitwise or would be efficient and easy, much easier than an add which has the extra baggage of the carry.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

EDIT ---

I determined it was using more macrocells by using ISE's reporting mechanism.
I also tried a few different things (but not the concatenation operator mentioned below) and everything added 7 macrocells except for the 'add'.  I was happy that the behavior was consistent.

As a side note, I added a single 3-input OR to my top-level schematic and fed it three signals (fault outputs) from different modules.  This added 9 macrocells.  You can bet I found a new way when I saw that, heh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is combine two smaller arrays into a larger array of signals then it's best to use the concatenation operator:

```
wire [5:0] tmp = {LL, RL};
```

With the above, `wire[5:3]` will be connected to `LL`, and `wire[2:0]` will be connected to `RL`

You can use it in any order like:

`wire[5:0] tmp = {RL, LL];`

Or even:

`wire[5:0] tmp = {LL[0], RL, LL[2:1];`

(you can see how this can be used to shift/rotate signals)

Still, I'm not sure why changing to the OR should use another 7 macrocells, it's possibly (probably) because the synthesis tool is inferring an adder with the + operator and the CPLD has an adder cell that it can use, as opposed to making the adder from a few gates.

How did you determine this? Did you check the technology schematic to see what's being created?
To help discover exactly what's happening, seeing the rest of your modules code would be helpful (also I can try it in ISE here)

EDIT - out of curiosity I wrote a small test module using the relevant bit of the above code. I tried synthesising (with default settings) for a Spartan-3A and the XC264A CPLD, with the `+` or the`|`. Both terms produced identical results for the Spartan and the CPLD, both in the technology viewer and the place and route macrocell usage report.
With this information, it looks like it must be something to do with the rest of the design and possibly the synthesis tool settings (optimisation, etc). The snippet above should just concatenate the two smaller signals into one larger one, so no logic should be necessary.

Comment: Yes, but the real puzzle is why didn't the synthesis tool reduce both of the original source constucts to this, and that can only be answered by examining its output in detail.

Comment: @Dave - Funny, I didn't see this message till about an hour after you (apparently) posted it (it seems the page is not updating automatically as usual) Anyway, I agree, just thinking about this now and having a mess around in ISE.

Comment: @DaveTweed and Oli - I updated the OP.  Not much to add except I also believe the forum isn't working quite right. Anyway, the code surrounding my problem 'add' has been changed quite a bit now - I've been shoe-horning my design into an XC2C64A.  My dev kit includes a 256...

Comment: (tiny syntax typo - the square bracket after "you can use it in any order" - it won't let me fix it. Similar typo in the next section also.)

Comment: Regarding posting more code, while I appreciate it, you guys will effortlessly whip my n00b code into shape and my learning adventure will end.  So I try to post as little as possible for this reason, knowing it will limit the help the board can give.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - No problems, don't want to spoil the fun :-) Anyway, see edits, I tried the bit of code above and got the same results both ways, so I'm not quite sure what's going on for you.

Comment: Oh, a related tidbit - Doing math using powers-of-2 (such as multiplying by 128 instead of 117) makes a material difference with respect to the resources consumed.  The synthesis engine is pretty darned smart.